# How to get the Delphi Projects MRU List?

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-11-alexandria

I am trying to get the Projects MRU List from specific Delphi versions:

```
function GetDelphiMRUList(const verstr: string; var MRUList: TStringList): Boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := False;
  MRUList.Text := '';
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\' + verstr);
    Result := Reg.KeyExists('Closed Projects');
    Reg.CloseKey;
    if Result then
    begin
      // How to get the MRUList?

    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var MRUList: TStringList;
  MRUList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if GetDelphiMRUList('22.0', MRUList) then
      CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: MRUList', MRUList);
  finally
    MRUList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am stuck at getting the list of closed projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on my system, the registry values are named `File_0`, `File_1`, and so on, so retrieving this list is easy:

```pascal
function GetDelphiMRUList(const verstr: string; MRUList: TStringList): Boolean;
begin
  var Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    Result := Reg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\' + verstr + '\Closed Projects', False);
    if Result then
    begin
      MRUList.Clear;
      var i := 0;
      while Reg.ValueExists('File_' + i.ToString) do
      begin
        MRUList.Add(Reg.ReadString('File_' + i.ToString));
        Inc(i);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(Please note that it doesn't make sense to let the `MRUList` be a `var` parameter.)

Usage:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if GetDelphiMRUList('21.0', List) then
      Memo1.Lines.Assign(List)
    else
      Memo1.Text := 'Couldn''t get MRU list.';
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! My questions: 1. Why don't you use `Reg.CloseKey;`? 2. What does `TBaseProject` and the numbers `1,1,1,1,1`mean? 3. Why do you prefer `Reg.OpenKey` over `OpenKeyReadOnly`?

Comment: (1) The `TRegistry.Destroy` destructor calls `CloseKey`, as you can see in `System.Win.Registry.pas`, probably close to line 255. (2) This is Embarcadero's implementation details. It is nowhere documented, and the format may be changed any time. You are not actually supposed to read these registry keys: they are only used internally by the BDS to save its settings. You have to ask the Embarcadero developers what the format is. And if you give them a huge pile of money, they might even promise you not to change this format in the next version of the BDS...

Comment: (3) I have always used `OpenKey` and never had a reason to use something else. In HKCU, you are allowed to do whatever you like, so permissions aren't going to be an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, Delphi does not have a Project Manager. So, IMO, it makes sense to create a custom one.

Comment: I would take this a step further. I would change the `MRUList` parameter to be `TStrings` so that `Memo1.Lines` can be passed directly to the function. And then internally, I would have the function use `TRegistry.GetValueNames()` and loop over the result, so there is no assumption over the names of the values.